# In OData, is there a way to request all the records in a table but receive them async fashion

Tags: windows, client, odata, paging

To speed searches i am loading all the customers to the client, about 30k or so. This takes a bit of time. I would like to load the customers async and in the background. Wondering if there is a way to do this easily.

Not tried too much at this point. Was working on main functionality, now headed back cleaning up some tech debt.

```
        var query = (DataServiceQuery<Customer>)Container.Customers
            .Expand(LibSettings._referralTypeExpand);
        return (await query.ExecuteAsync()).ToList();
```

Ideally, would like to issue an ODATA query that would return some of the records over and over until all have been downloaded to the client. Or, if there is a better way to get the search times on the client almost immediately, I am very open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my answer is that I am an idiot. The call above returns about 30,000 records in about 12 seconds. I then enumerate the IEnumerable to a List object which takes about 1.5 minutes. So I will be looking at ways to speed up that process, turns out the fetch from the server through the OData interface is fine.